# How to make a react application to run on port 8080 and 0.0.0.0?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, package.json

I have built an **react** application which is running at **localhost:8080**, now i want to change it to **0.0.0.0:80** to make it **access publicly** but unfortunately i'm not able to access.

```
Webpack file:

var config = {
   entry: [
    './main.js'
 ],

   output: {
      path:'D:\\reactApps\\RouterExample',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
    inline: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 80,
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         },{
            test: /\.css$/,
             exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'style-loader'
         }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
             exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'css-loader',
            query: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
         }
      ]
   }

}

module.exports = config;

package.json file:

{
  "name": "routerexample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "new app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.7.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.1",
    "react-bootstrap-alert": "^1.0.7",
    "react-bootstrap-dialog": "^0.9.1",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-number-format": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Edit-1:

I want to configure my application to be accessible through a url for example(xyz.com) instead of localhost, how it can be acheivable..?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: are you using nodejs?

Comment: Yeah of course..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to http://localhost:80

0.0.0.0 isn't a legal address.  It just means, whatever address the machine is assigned.

Comment: @ManikantaB -- a lot of things are simple once you see the trick.

Comment: Do you have any idea that we can change the accessing url from localhost to xyz.com??

Comment: @ManikantaB -- I do, but that's a different question.  Write it up, describing your whole situation (what OS are you on?  Do you want everybody to be able to access it from xyz.com or just you?  What are you planning to do with it?), and put a link to it here in the comments.